# Как прочитать параметры из строки запроса Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Имеется строка запроса, который приходит в виде строки, как входной параметр метода. Это не ActivatedRoute.

```
http://localhost:4200/users?param1=en&param2=nk
```

Как мне прочитать значения param1 и param2
Пробовал так:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}
let srcStr = 'http://localhost:4200/users?param1=en&param2=nk';
const tree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl(srcStr);
console.log('params = ', tree.queryParams);
```

В результате получаю пустой объект
Или может можно это как то по другому реализовать?

Comment: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/get-query-parameters-in-angular/

Comment: Этот пример для ActivatedRoute, т.е. для пути самого приложения. А у меня путь, это строка которую получаю как входной параметр метода. Я не знаю как ее поместить в ActivatedRoute. А для UrlTree этот пример не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
let srcStr = 'http://localhost:4200/users?param1=en&param2=nk';
const url = new URL(srcStr);
console.log(url.searchParams.get('param1'));
console.log(url.searchParams.get('param2'));
```